# Button close, button minimize and button setting are not working using the below javascript

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Button close, button minimize and button setting are not working using the below javascript.

I use boostrap 2.0.4

```
//datatable
    $('.datatable').dataTable({
            "sDom": "<'row-fluid'<'span6'l><'span6'f>r>t<'row-fluid'<'span12'i><'span12 center'p>>",
            "sPaginationType": "bootstrap",
            "oLanguage": {
            "sLengthMenu": "_MENU_ records per page"
            }
        } );
    $('.btn-close').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        if (e.target === this)
                $(this).parent().parent().parent().fadeOut();
    });
    $('.btn-minimize').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var $target = $(this).parent().parent().next('.box-content');
        if($target.is(':visible')) $('i',$(this)).removeClass('icon-chevron-up').addClass('icon-chevron-down');
        else                       $('i',$(this)).removeClass('icon-chevron-down').addClass('icon-chevron-up');
        $target.slideToggle();
    });
    $('.btn-setting').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#myModal').modal('show');
    });
```

EDIT 1: I am trying to use this template table http://usman.it/themes/charisma/table.html
You can download the table.html file there. Another thing that I could not understand is when I check the html code, there is no SEARCH text input, no page navigation. How do they come out to the browser?

EDIT 2: I am using Google App Engine, Django, Jinja2

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/on/ look at on() function from jquery

Comment: Share your relevant HTML code.

Comment: Not working is not a good enough description. Do you have any errors? What is the specific problems you are facing ? Can you post a fiddle?

Comment: The error is that when I click on those buttons, nothing happen.

Comment: by the way, i am using Google App Engine, is there any problem that the template may not work with GAE?

Answer (score 1):

If you are dynamically adding the `button` to the `DOM`, then `click()` may not work.

Try this out:

```
$(document).on("click", '.btn-close', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    if (e.target === this)
            $(this).parent().parent().parent().fadeOut();
});

$(document).on("click", '.btn-minimize', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var $target = $(this).parent().parent().next('.box-content');
    if($target.is(':visible')) $('i',$(this)).removeClass('icon-chevron-up').addClass('icon-chevron-down');
    else                       $('i',$(this)).removeClass('icon-chevron-down').addClass('icon-chevron-up');
    $target.slideToggle();
});

$(document).on("click", '.btn-setting', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#myModal').modal('show');
});
```

Comment: Your buttons are working fine. Which browser are you trying on?

Comment: I am using Firefox 18.0. I tried with Google Chrome, but also does not work

Comment: Try taking out the relevant code and creating a sample app to check the issue.

Answer (score -1):

```
$('.datatable').dataTable({
        "sDom": "<'row-fluid'<'span6'l><'span6'f>r>t<'row-fluid'<'span12'i><'span12 center'p>>",
        "sPaginationType": "bootstrap",
        "oLanguage": {
        "sLengthMenu": "_MENU_ records per page"
        }
    } );
$('.btn-close').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent().parent().parent().fadeOut();
});
$('.btn-minimize').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var $target = $(this).parent().parent().next('.box-content');
    if($target.is(':visible')) 
      $('i',$(this)).removeClass('icon-chevron-up').addClass('icon-chevron-down');
    else
      $('i',$(this)).removeClass('icon-chevron-down').addClass('icon-chevron-up');
    $target.slideToggle();
});
$('.btn-setting').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#myModal').modal('show');
});
```